# ошибка при работе программы Segmentation fault

Tags: linux, c

Не могу понять откуда "идет" ошибка. Программа работает и компилируеться , но как только доходит до строки

`strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, iface, IFNAMSIZ); // append this structur (ifr) names CAN intarface`

то происходит Segmentation fault .

Зато когда напрямую код в `void main(int argc, char **argv)` и вызываю из терминала `./progran can0`   работает без жалобы  как только перенашу в одельную функию так сразу проблеммы :(((

Вот код

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

#include <linux/can.h>
#include <linux/can/bcm.h>

#define PROGNAME "socketcan-bcm-demo"
#define VERSION  "1.0.0"

#define MSGID   (0x0C0)
#define MSGLEN  (3)
#define NFRAMES (4)

#define DELAY (10000)

void start(int argc, char *argv);

static sig_atomic_t sigval;

static void onsig(int val)
{
    sigval = (sig_atomic_t)val;
}

static void usage(void)
{
    puts("Usage: " PROGNAME "[OPTIONS] IFACE\n"
         "Where:\n"
         "  IFACE    CAN network interface\n"
         "Options:\n"
         "  -h       Display this help then exit\n"
         "  -v       Display version info then exit\n");
}

static void version(void)
{
    puts(PROGNAME " " VERSION "\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    start(2, "can0");
}

void start(int argc, char *argv)
{
    unsigned int i;
    int opt;
    int s;
    char *iface;
    struct sockaddr_can addr;
    struct ifreq ifr;
    printf("start %d \n", 1);
    struct can_msg
    {
        struct bcm_msg_head msg_head;
        struct can_frame frame[NFRAMES];
    } msg;
    printf("start %d \n", 2);
    /* Check if at least one argument was specified */
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fputs("Too few arguments!\n", stderr);
        usage();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("start %d \n", 3);
    /* Parse command line options */
//    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "hv")) != -1)
//    {
//        switch (opt)
//        {
//        case 'h':
//            usage();
//            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
//        case 'v':
//            version();
//            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
//        default:
//            usage();
//            return EXIT_FAILURE;
//        }
//    }

      iface = argv[0];
//    printf("start %d \n", 4);
//    /* Exactly one command line argument must remain; the interface to use */
//    if (optind == (argc - 1))
//    {
//        iface = argv[optind];
//    }
//    else
//    {
//        fputs("Only one interface may be used!\n", stderr);
//        usage();
//        return EXIT_FAILURE;
//    }

    printf("start %d \n", 5);
    /* Register signal handlers */
    if (signal(SIGINT, onsig)    == SIG_ERR ||
        signal(SIGTERM, onsig)   == SIG_ERR ||
        signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN) == SIG_ERR)
    {
        perror(PROGNAME);
        return errno;
    }
    printf("start %d \n", 6);
    /* Open the CAN interface */
    s = socket(PF_CAN, SOCK_DGRAM, CAN_BCM);
    if (s < 0)
    {
        perror(PROGNAME ": socket");
        return errno;
    }
    printf("start %d \n", 7);
    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, iface, IFNAMSIZ);
    if (ioctl(s, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr) < 0)
    {
        perror(PROGNAME ": ioctl");
        return errno;
    }
    printf("start %d \n", 8);
    addr.can_family = AF_CAN;
    addr.can_ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;
    if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
    {
        perror(PROGNAME ": connect");
        return errno;
    }
    printf("start %d \n", 9);
    /* Setup code */
    sigval = 0;

    /* Set up cyclic messages. Note that both SETTIMER and STARTTIMER are
     * required as flags in order to continue transmitting.
     */
    msg.msg_head.opcode  = TX_SETUP;
    msg.msg_head.can_id  = 0;
    msg.msg_head.flags   = SETTIMER | STARTTIMER;
    msg.msg_head.nframes = NFRAMES;
    msg.msg_head.count   = 0;

    /* Set the time interval value to 1200 ms */
    msg.msg_head.ival2.tv_sec = 1;
    msg.msg_head.ival2.tv_usec = 200000;

    /* Create the example messages */
    for (i = 0; i < NFRAMES; ++i)
    {
        struct can_frame * const frame = msg.frame + i;
        frame->can_id = MSGID + i;
        frame->can_dlc = MSGLEN;
        memset(frame->data, i, MSGLEN);
    }

    /* Register the cyclic messages. Note that all of the messages in the msg
     * struct will be sent with the same periodicity because they share the
     * same bcm_msg_head setup data.
     */
    if (write(s, &msg, sizeof(msg)) < 0)
    {
        perror(PROGNAME ": write: TX_SETUP");
        return errno;
    }
    printf("start %d \n", 10);
    printf("Cyclic messages registed with SocketCAN!\n"
           "Use a tool such as \"candump %s\" to view the messages.\n"
           "These messages will continue to transmit so long as the socket\n"
           "used to communicate with SocketCAN remains open. In other words,\n"
           "close this program with SIGINT or SIGTERM in order to gracefully\n"
           "stop transmitting.\n",
           iface);

    /* Spin forever here */
    while (0 == sigval) usleep(DELAY);

    puts("\nGoodbye!");

    /* Close the CAN interface */
    if (close(s) < 0)
    {
        perror(PROGNAME ": close");
        return errno;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

---

***По сути проблемма в  том что хочу "компоненты" `main(int argc, char **argv)` 
"перекинуть" в функцию `start(2, "can0");` как это сделать (правильно) ??***

Comment: Где создается/инициализируется iface до использвания?

Comment: @AlexanderChernin ой , добавил :3  `iface = argv[0];`

Comment: Вам не кажется подозрительным вот что: Вы объявляете функцию как `void start(int argc, char *argv)`, откуда ясно, что `argv` - простой указатель (ладно, пусть даже это строка). При вызове Вы туда скармливаете строку `"can0"`... А ниже в коде Вы делаете `iface = argv[0];`. Т.е Вы в указатель `iface` заносите символ 'c'. И что Вы ожидаете дальше? Что находится по адресу, который соответствует номеру буквы 'c'?

Comment: Что такое `iface = argv[0];`? Это некомпилируемо в С. Какой смысл пытаться запускать программу, если уже на этапе компиляции вы получили от компилятора диагностическое сообщения о некорректности программы?

Comment: @Vladimir   а как правильно ?? я вопрос обновил , и даже смог получить "выхлоп" полу-рабочая программа, Сообщение по кану получаю "С0  00 00 00 " а потом  Segmentation fault . Но я в общем не понимаю как надо делать

Comment: @AnT я не заканчивал физмат. Добавил сообщение в комментариях а также обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("start %d \n", 7);
if(strlen(iface)>=IFNAMSIZ)
   printf("device name is error.\n"),exit(0);
strcpy(ifr.ifr_name,iface);
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем вот ответ.

Проблема была в том что не заметил что привожу `char *argv` к  `char *iface;`  из-за чего выпрыгнула ошибка.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

#include <linux/can.h>
#include <linux/can/bcm.h>

#define PROGNAME "socketcan-bcm-demo"
#define VERSION  "1.0.0"

#define MSGID   (0x0C0)
#define MSGLEN  (3)
#define NFRAMES (4)

#define DELAY (10000)

void start(int argc, char *argv);

static sig_atomic_t sigval;

static void onsig(int val)
{
    sigval = (sig_atomic_t)val;
}

static void usage(void)
{
    puts("Usage: " PROGNAME "[OPTIONS] IFACE\n"
         "Where:\n"
         "  IFACE    CAN network interface\n"
         "Options:\n"
         "  -h       Display this help then exit\n"
         "  -v       Display version info then exit\n");
}

static void version(void)
{
    puts(PROGNAME " " VERSION "\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    start(2, "can0");
}

void start(int argc, char *argv)
{
    unsigned int i;
    int opt;
    int s;
    char *iface;
    struct sockaddr_can addr;
    struct ifreq ifr;
    printf("start %d \n", 1);
    struct can_msg
    {
        struct bcm_msg_head msg_head;
        struct can_frame frame[NFRAMES];
    } msg;
    printf("start %d \n", 2);
    /* Check if at least one argument was specified */
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fputs("Too few arguments!\n", stderr);
        usage();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("start %d \n", 3);
    /* Parse command line options */
//    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "hv")) != -1)
//    {
//        switch (opt)
//        {
//        case 'h':
//            usage();
//            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
//        case 'v':
//            version();
//            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
//        default:
//            usage();
//            return EXIT_FAILURE;
//        }
//    }

//      iface = argv[0];
//    printf("start %d \n", 4);
//    /* Exactly one command line argument must remain; the interface to use */
//    if (optind == (argc - 1))
//    {
//        iface = argv[optind];
//    }
//    else
//    {
//        fputs("Only one interface may be used!\n", stderr);
//        usage();
//        return EXIT_FAILURE;
//    }

    printf("start %d \n", 5);
    /* Register signal handlers */
    if (signal(SIGINT, onsig)    == SIG_ERR ||
        signal(SIGTERM, onsig)   == SIG_ERR ||
        signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN) == SIG_ERR)
    {
        perror(PROGNAME);
        return errno;
    }
    printf("start %d \n", 6);
    /* Open the CAN interface */
    s = socket(PF_CAN, SOCK_DGRAM, CAN_BCM);
    if (s < 0)
    {
        perror(PROGNAME ": socket");
        return errno;
    }
    printf("start %d \n", 7);
    if(strlen(argv)>=IFNAMSIZ)
    {
        printf("device name is error.\n");
        return errno;
    }
    strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, argv);

    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, argv, IFNAMSIZ);
    if (ioctl(s, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr) < 0)
    {
        perror(PROGNAME ": ioctl");
        return errno;
    }
    printf("start %d \n", 8);
    addr.can_family = AF_CAN;
    addr.can_ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;
    if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
    {
        perror(PROGNAME ": connect");
        return errno;
    }
    printf("start %d \n", 9);
    /* Setup code */
    sigval = 0;

    /* Set up cyclic messages. Note that both SETTIMER and STARTTIMER are
     * required as flags in order to continue transmitting.
     */
    msg.msg_head.opcode  = TX_SETUP;
    msg.msg_head.can_id  = 0;
    msg.msg_head.flags   = SETTIMER | STARTTIMER;
    msg.msg_head.nframes = NFRAMES;
    msg.msg_head.count   = 0;

    /* Set the time interval value to 1200 ms */
    msg.msg_head.ival2.tv_sec = 1;
    msg.msg_head.ival2.tv_usec = 200000;

    /* Create the example messages */
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < 4; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d \n", i1);
        struct can_frame * const frame = msg.frame + i1;
        frame->can_id = MSGID + i1;
        frame->can_dlc = MSGLEN;
        memset(frame->data, i1, MSGLEN);
    }

    /* Register the cyclic messages. Note that all of the messages in the msg
     * struct will be sent with the same periodicity because they share the
     * same bcm_msg_head setup data.
     */
    if (write(s, &msg, sizeof(msg)) < 0)
    {
        perror(PROGNAME ": write: TX_SETUP");
        return errno;
    }
    // незнаю почему но на мини компике выдает ошибку именно на этот принтф (станционарном всё ок )
    printf("start %d \n", 10);
    //  printf("Cyclic messages registed with SocketCAN!\n"
    //       "Use a tool such as \"candump %s\" to view the messages.\n"
    //       "These messages will continue to transmit so long as the socket\n"
    //       "used to communicate with SocketCAN remains open. In other words,\n"
    //       "close this program with SIGINT or SIGTERM in order to gracefully\n"
    //       "stop transmitting.\n",
    //      iface);

    /* Spin forever here */
    while (0 == sigval) usleep(DELAY);

    puts("\nGoodbye!");

    /* Close the CAN interface */
    if (close(s) < 0)
    {
        perror(PROGNAME ": close");
        return errno;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

В общем  так, очень задело что мне так и не дали ответ у читывая что я не заканчивал физмат как всё эти отличники . Могли бы и помочь.

Comment: Напишите подробнее, какую проблему решает ваш ответ. На данный момент вопрос-ответ бесполезен для будущих посетителей. Если вопрос был вызван опечаткой или некорректной работой с указателями, его, вероятнее всего, стоит просто удалить.